# What is the difference between Cappuccino and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cappuccino

I have been working with node JS for about two weeks and I am liking it a lot. I came cross something called Cappuccino; it sounds like what I want to use to develop a web application. As a beginner, can someone assist with explaining what exactly Cappuccino is and how it fits into node?

Really my hold up with developing an application is that I come from a VB background and I am use to forms to design my desktop apps. I do not want to be limited with a WYSIWYG type of IDE, that is why I started with node.

Comment: What does node have to do with a wysiwyg IDE ?

Comment: Just my reasoning to learn node.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What sort of web application? There are... many JS libraries/frameworks. It's a jungle.

My strong advice is to build several things, from very small to less small, using pure Javascript. Otherwise you will, I promise, remain forever cloudy on what the language is vs. the frameworks layered on top. JS is very mutable and frameworks have a tendency to create new semantics on top of the core language. The downside of learning by using these is you ever fully understand the complexities and subtleties of the language itself, nor do you ever really understand what those frameworks are giving you (in many cases, things you don't need or that artificially constrain you). Be wary of framework entanglement.

As you get used to writing simple scripts in a text editor (try Sublime Text if you want something much better than that), you'll begin to appreciate when and why you might want help from a framework. Move on to jQuery, as it's the most widely used library and is either a dependency or heavily informs the style of many other libraries out there.

I'm working on a blog post about the topic of frameworks, by no means comprehensive as there are hundreds of them it seems. Specifically, breaking down about 20-30 major players by their intended domain (e.g. DOM manipulation, Single Page Applications, data-binding, MVC, etc.) and strengths and weaknesses.

There are some great books and YouTube videos going into many aspects of modern JS. Anything by Douglas Crockford I recommend (especially book or video "Javascript: The Good Parts". He's pedantic but wise and generally on the money. Then for more inspirational stuff about recent/upcoming changes to the language, watch some stuff from the Google I/O events. Check out HTML5rocks.com for articles on some cutting edge features available in the browser. There are many many more resources, but these are some good ones.

Oh and be sure you are familiar with the dev tools in the browser. I personally recommend Chrome as best of breed. Learn the keyboard shortcut to open it on any page, inspect, and noodle. There are some fancy things such tools support like live editing/saving of source, profiling and debugging, DOM/CSS inspection, and on and on. There are other free and non-free IDEs but IMHO they are too much overhead for someone just learning (and many advanced JS developers use Sublime Text).

P.S.: jQuery, per its design goals, is still going strong but is aimed for obsolescence as browsers increasingly are converging on true standards (ES5, HTML5, CSS3). Even so, for many apps, its shorthand semantics are much better than even the newly supported standards for many things. And it's not going away any time soon, just becoming less important. Like IE. Ignore IE unless you need to build things for work.

Comment: I have a database that collects the transactions of maintenance for car repair. There are over 500,000 transactions so all I want to simply do is use node to filter the data and display on a webpage in a listbox or some sort of widget. There is no writing it is strictly reading from an oracle database.The user would have the ability to select garage, mechanic and it would pass the parameters to the query. I subscribe to safari books and have been reading anything I can get my hands on and listen to the you tube videos in the car. I can code the database aspects it is just designing I am stuck

Comment: Well depends how much you want to learn JS vs. get a quick and dirty app going. Node.js should work just fine to connect to DB and return results of a search. If your site doesn't need to be maintained (when does that happen), you might get away with never learning JS more thoroughly and leave it at that. If you go the learning route, there are many ways to connect to backed DBs, including straight from the client to a backend provider (often free for smallish applications).

Comment: Checkout Backbone for a good way to model the data on the client. It's mature and fairly easy to understand, promotes good separate of model and view. From there, consider Parse.com, a backend provider that provides a client-side API based on Backbone. This gives you the backend support for free.

Comment: Thanks and I totally want to learn js because I think node is the way of the future, I am actually going to my first meetup on js next Saturday. I am going to play around with both angular and backbone. Are these both the same as something like express?

Comment: Awesome! To your question: no. And I would recommend maybe not playing around with Angular just yet. It will make your head explode. The ubiquitous demo of data-binding to a text field makes it seems like everything is going to be that easy. The problem is it uses some very advanced CS approaches (and then names many of them badly) to ultimately make development much less of a pain, but the learning curve is STEEP. YMMV

Comment: Okay, this is going to sound stupid because the past two weeks has been nothing but Node and Express. With Backbone is there an app generator or is this strictly a js library similar to a jquery where you write your scripts in an html doc and access the library source? Or is there something in sublime that lets me run the code to test?

Comment: You may be unrealistically hung up on the idea of apps being generated from some meta-data. Such things *exist* but you will spend more time trying to get them to work than the time they will save, until you are more clear on JS and the ecosystem. Backbone is a library you include in your web page. To test running code, best bet is in the browser with dev tools. To test more rigorously, check out test tools like Mocha (browser or server-side). But, these will all add learning curve compared to just start writing. Your first app is going to not be the best way to do it, but you'll get it done.

Comment: I already have. The problem here is not knowing which parts are less familiar to you, or I could offer (maybe) more specific advice. But given my overall read, I think you should start coding the wrong/naive way and then seek tools that make your coding easier. What, to you, are the harder problems to solve right now?

Comment: If you want to run tests I recommend just writing some pure javascript ones.  Later try mocha.  I agree with Jason Boyd that you shouldn't try to use power tools until you are good with the basic ones; you might have initial success but when a problem happens it likely will be confusing/frustrating to fix.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see, Cappuccino is a client-side framework of some kind, in the same kind of vein as Backbone.js or Angular.js, and is in no way comparable with Node.js. They run in completely different environments (Node on the server, Cappuccino in the browser).

A client-side framework like Cappuccino would be used to implement web apps that needed to do a lot of work on the client side. For instance, if you implemented a real-time web app with Node, you might use it to simplify inserting new content into the DOM.

I haven't used Cappuccino, and it doesn't seem to be all that popular. It seems to be squarely aimed at people with a background in Cocoa development on Mac OS X, so if that's not what you're after I would recommend you look elsewhere. Client-side MVC frameworks are very useful for some use cases, and the big four seem to be Angular.js, Ember.js, Backbone.js and Knockout.js, so I would check out one of them before considering Cappuccino. Knockout is very easy to learn, but lacks routing, which was a deal-breaker for me, so I switched to Backbone. Considering how much mindshare it seems to have, I would probably now go for AngularJS.

Comment: Matthew, thanks and can you please give me some guidance on what tool I can use to build my front end application? Is there something other than jade that will allow forms with buttons, auto complete text box, etc??? Thanks again

Comment: If you're talking about widgets and things like that, then there are a few options. Twitter Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/) gives you things like buttons quickly and easily. For more complex widgets, take a look at jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/)

Comment: Matthew, it would be somthing like in the link below, I just do not know where it fits in the big picture!!! Is this something that I would use with jade?http://taitems.tumblr.com/post/482577430/introducing-aristo-a-jquery-ui-theme

Comment: No, those frameworks are nothing like Express. Express is server-side, while those frameworks are client-side. They solve completely different problems

Comment: You can use jQuery UI with Jade and Express, however IMHO Jade is a bit too different to regular HTML, and so is probably a bit too much for a new user. You may be better off using a templating engine that is closer to normal HTML, such as Handlebars.

Comment: Case in point: My first Node.js app is at https://github.com/matthewbdaly/rabbitrabbitrabbit, and it uses Express on the server side to serve the main page and send the data. On the client side it uses Backbone to render new messages in real time as they are added.

Comment: Actually the tutorials on jade have been great, but now I am right where I started. I was looking to begin designing of the webpage and started looking at Cappuccino.

Answer (score 1):

Cappuccino is a client side framework built on top of Objective-J which in turn is a complete language built on javascript. It's intended solely for building desktop class applications that happen to run in a browser.

Objective-J adds features to javascript (like classical inheritance) in the same way Objective-C adds them to C. You can use Objective-J with node but probably not most of Cappuccino. Cappuccino is the framework that lets you build rich user interfaces in a way that allows you to completely ignore that you're working with html.

I would not recommend Cappuccino as a first foray into web development unless you really only want to build a business application and you are already a proficient Mac OS X or iPhone developer. It will not help at all to teach you about the web.

Cappuccino is (imho) head and shoulders above everything else in its league, but it is intended (or most useful) for a very tiny niche.

If you're still interested in Cappuccino (or Objective-J) you should really [check out the learn section](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/learn/) of [the Cappuccino project website](http://www.cappuccino-project.org/)